# Wget return code if file not updated

Tags: linux, return-value, wget

I have command like this for the cron task

```
 wget  -N -q http://host.com/dump.file; echo $
```

Which return 0 even if file actually never downloaded because it the same. Any chance to have 0 only then file actually has been downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling wget directly, you could write a script which calls wget, and before/after captures its "changed" timestamp.  For instance, GNU coreutils [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) returns a high-resolution timestamp, such as

```
Change: 2015-02-10 04:42:23.000000000 -0500
```

In the script, you could save this information into a variable, e.g.,

```
before="`stat dump.file |fgrep Change:`"
wget  -N -q http://host.com/dump.file
after="`stat dump.file |fgrep Change:`"
test "x$before" != "x$after"
```

Comment: I'm asking about wget option. Not bash crunches. O probably some other utility which have proper reaction.

Comment: If you are interested solely in wget, you should read its manual page (in that case, the question is not relevant to SO).

Comment: This is a helpful answer to the question even if it is not what the questioner was looking for. By the way, grep is not needed for high-resolution time stamps. `stat -c %.Z` gets the last change time as seconds since the Epoch, with nine digits of precision after the decimal point.